# Array.prototype effect jQuery event handler binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a strange phenomenon about that when defining `Array.prototype` with a function method then binding any element with jQuery event handler, the binding elements would have the event referring to that `Array.prototype` method function but would not trigger, for example:

```
Array.prototype.whatever = function() {
    alert('Show on event listeners but not trigger');
};

$('a').click(function() {
    alert('');
});
```

[JS Fiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/amd50vor/16/)

Then use Browser's development tool to check that binding element, the events would include that customized `Array.prototype` function which should not appear.

For each action's events, one of the event is jQuery event handler but another is unusual `Array.prototype` method function.

[image]

I'm wondering what's wrong with it, thanks.

> Development tool: Firefox & Chrome with Framework listeners

Comment: You are *probably* looking at the wrong execution context. JSFiddle executes the fiddle in an iframe, which is not the default execution context. Try `console.log(Array.prototype)`.

Comment: This one's for Chrome, but Firefox has a similar approach. See "Selecting Execution Context" section: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: @NisargShah This issue is also occurred in single web page, which the element displays the `Array.prototype` method event with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I am still a bit unclear on this part: "the events would include that customized Array.prototype function." Can you clarify what exactly you are looking for in the events?

Comment: Sorry for my expression. For the image example, there should not have two events for each action. One of the event is jQuery event handler but another is unusual `Array.prototype` method function.

Comment: Yup that is very strange. Both Firefox and Chrome are showing that `Array.prototype.whatever` function on `click` and `change` event handlers. Even with codepen I am getting the same result. Might be a bug in the Dev Tools...